# jQuery val() inside display: none

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="#addFriend" rel="facebox" title="[+] add <?php echo $showU["full_name"]; ?> as friend">
    <div class="addFriend"></div></A>

<div id="addFriend" style="display:none; margin: auto;">
    <form action="javascript:DoFriendRequest()" method="post">
        <input name="commentFriend" type="text" id="commentFriend" value="" size="22"> 
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>
```

My form when it's inside this element which is a jquery lightbox, the field `#commentFriend` get empty value in DoFriendRequest

```
function DoFriendRequest() {
    var wrapperId = '#insert_svar';
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "misc/AddFriendRequest.php",
        data: {
            mode: 'ajax',
            comment : $('#commentFriend').val() 
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            $(wrapperId).prepend(msg);
            $('#commentFriend').val("");
        }
    });
}
```

**Updated answer**

But when I remove the `display:none`, it works. How can I solve this?

Comment: First, you should fix your HTML: You're missing a `</form>`

Comment: Can you show the entire code of where you're getting this?  Also is this `<form>` repeated more than once in the page?

Comment: If you have multiple form(s) on a page and haven't closed one. it will impact the others.

Comment: The form is not repeated more than once on the page. There's 2 other forms on the page, but that is after this one? I just doublechecked and they are all closed

Comment: I updated the answer, with full JS and link to the lightbox

Comment: @Karem - What confuses me is you cay it works without the `display:none`, but from what you posted the form would be hidden complete with it on there....so how does it "not work" with it, isn't the `<form>` completely hidden? How are you even submitting to see it doesn't work?

Comment: @Nick OK, why i say so is when i remove display:none from the div style and refresh my page, I can now see the form without clicking and turning display it in a lightbox. Now when i type in the comment field and submit, i see with firebug that it has sended the variable comment=test123123, so its working fine without the display: none style.

Comment: @Karem - Is that problem solved? Or do you know have an issue with the lightbox display? Do you want the page to load with the form initially hidden?

Comment: @Peter the problem is not solved as it only works without the display:none attribute, and i need that display:none attribute in order to have it in the lightbox and not show before it has been clicked on it

Comment: @Karem - Then you should include the function that controls the visibility of `#addFriend`. I don't see it.

Comment: @Peter : <a href="#addFriend" rel="facebox".. Im using facebox jquery plugin for my lightbox, I dont quite understand what I should include?

Comment: @Karem - I've never used facebox, but presumably there is a function that changes the display attribute of `#addFriend` when something is done. That's the function that should be included.

Comment: @Peter i thought that display: none did it, and then some function in facebox.js calls after it and shows it in a styled box (lightbox) ?

Answer (score 27):

For fields with `display:none`, it seems that `val()` does not work.

I bypass this behavior with `attr()`:

```
$('input').attr('value',myNewValue);
```

Comment: This is for changing the value of the input, we are looking to get the real-time value of the input when shown to the user to fill up.

Comment: `var currentInputValue = $('input').attr('value')`

Comment: It doesn't work with "display: none" and gives an "undefined" value. According to the documentation and my tests, the attr() method only works for getting the predefined value="'" attribute from the DOM and not the real-time value entered by the user as with the val() method.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways you can go about this;

1. Make the element visible, update it, then hide it again.
2. [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the element from the DOM, make it visible, update it, hide it, and then re-insert into the DOM.
3. [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element, make it visible, update it, hide it, insert it into the DOM and remove the original element.

Approach #2 and #3 are probably your best options, since these won't trigger a re-draw. All operations are done to the elements "outside" of the DOM (in memory, if you will). This way your UI wont jump/skitter/shift.

Approach #3:

```
$(function ()
{
    var e = $("...");
    var c = e.clone();

    c.show();
    c.html("...");
    c.hide();

    e.after(c);
    e.remove();        
});
```

A shoter version (not tested):

```
var e = $("...");

e.append(e.clone().show().html("...").hide()).remove();
```

Approach #2:

*Note: you will need a container which you can re-insert the detached element into*

```
$(function ()
{
    var e = $("...");
    var c = $("container");

    e.detach();
    e.show();
    e.html("...");
    e.hide();
    c.add(e);    
});
```

And just for good measure - not tested - the shorter version:

```
$("container").add($("...").detach().show().html("...").hide());
```

Comment: could you go with an example on how you deatch,visible,update,hide,re-insert ? I have never used those before

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. None of the above solution worked for me.
I finnaly I could get the value of my hidden input by using DOM element:

```
var el = document.getElementById("commentFriend");
var hiddenValue =  el.getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 2):

Too late answer but maybe for someone is good. If you want have some elements with display:none and use functions of jQuery or JS you need hidden the elements with jQuery first and next all is good, you can do it with addClass and define your class or with `.hide()` and `.show()`.

For example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('element1').hide();
    $('element2').hide();

    var element1 = $('element1').val();
    console.log(element1);
});
```

Is the same with CSS you create for example class .hidden and do this.

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('element1').addClass('hidden');
    $('element2').addClass('hidden');

    var element1 = $('element1').val();
    console.log(element1);
});
```

Whit JavaScript do it adding CSS class to your element.