# Set textbox value which is dynamically added has display:none property in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here the scenario is i have added `dynamic row` to table having tds as `textbox` and `span` tag,

Now am doing some calculation here in demo you will see a multiple factor textbox , on change will update my table to last column i.e (Calculated area provided) ,

Problem i facing is i need to fetch the updated calculate value of last column (four wheeler), I am able to update span but not textbox

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SSNfZ/14/)**

**JS code:**

```
$("#apnd_tr").on('click',function(){
$(".Total_result").parents('tr').before(row_1cnt);
    $(".Total_result").parents('tr').before(row_2cnt);
});



var arrParkingRowIds = new Array();
        $("#myMultipleFactor").on('input', function () {

            var get_factorValue = $(this).val();
            var counter = 0;
            $("#myTable [class*=id_]").each(function () {
                counter++;
                if (counter == 4) {
                    var da = $(this).attr('class');
                    var fourWhlrValue = $("." + da).find("#txtprovidedNoParfetch").val();
                    var setResultProvidedParking = Number(fourWhlrValue) * Number(get_factorValue);
                    $("." + da).find("#txtprovidedPAfetch").next().html(setResultProvidedParking.toFixed(2));
                    $("." + da).find("#txtprovidedPAfetch").val(setResultProvidedParking);
                    counter = 0;
                    arrParkingRowIds.push(da);
                }
            });
        });

        $("#mValue").on('click', function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < arrParkingRowIds.length; i++) {
                var gData = arrParkingRowIds[i];
                alert($("." + gData).find('td:eq(7)').html());
            }
        });



var row_1cnt='<tr class="id_108">   <td colspan="8">       <input type="text" value="2323232323" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="TextTitleFetch" class="prk_txt_style" /><span class="spnrowset">Row Bunglows</span>       <div class="save_prk_row btn btn-mini btn-primary myBTNTEST" id="id_108" style="display: none;">save</div>    </td>  </tr>   <tr class="id_108">    <td id="tdSrNofetch">1</td>    <td id="tdtypeOfParkingfetch">Four wheeler</td>  <td>      <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPRFetch" /><span class="spnrowset">3</span>        </td>  <td>            <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedPRfetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>     </td>      <td>     <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style clsCal1_108" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredNoParfetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>    </td>     <td>            <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedNoParfetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>     </td>   <td>     <input type="text" disabled="" value="9" class="prk_txt_style clsShow1_108" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPAfetch"><span class="spnrowset">9</span>     </td>  <td>    <input type="text" value="9" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedPAfetch"><span class="spnrowset spnadd">9</span>   </td> </tr> <tr class="id_108">   <td>2</td>   <td>Two wheeler</td>    <td>       <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPR2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span> </td>   <td>         <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedPR2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>  </td>   <td>   <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style clsCal2_108" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredNoPar2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span> </td>   <td>  <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedNoPar2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>  </td>  <td>    <input type="text" disabled="" value="9" class="prk_txt_style clsShow2_108" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPA2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">9</span> </td> <td>  <input type="text" value="9.00" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedPA2fetch"><span class="spnrowset spnadd">9.00</span> </td></tr> <tr class="id_108">    <td>3</td>    <td>bicycle</td>    <td>  <input type="text" value="3" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style" id="txtrequiredPR3fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span> </td>  <td><input type="text" value="3" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style" id="txtprovidedPR3fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span> </td>  <td>  <input type="text" value="3" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style clsCal3_108" id="txtrequiredNP3fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>  </td>    <td>        <input type="text" value="3" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style" id="txtprovidedNP3fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>     </td>   <td>      <input type="text" disabled="" value="0" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPA3fetch" class="prk_txt_style clsShow3_108"><span class="spnrowset">0</span>   </td>     <td>          <input type="text" value="0.00" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style" id="txtprovidedPA3fetch"><span class="spnrowset spnadd">0.00</span>  </td> </tr>';


var row_2cnt=' <tr class="id_109">   <td colspan="8"> <input type="text" value="2323232323" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="TextTitleFetch" class="prk_txt_style" /><span class="spnrowset">Hospital</span>  <div class="save_prk_row btn btn-mini btn-primary myBTNTEST" id="id_108" style="display: none;">save</div>  </td>  </tr>   <tr class="id_109">  <td id="tdSrNofetch">1</td>        <td id="tdtypeOfParkingfetch">Four wheeler</td>        <td>  <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPRFetch" /><span class="spnrowset">3</span> </td>  <td>   <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedPRfetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>    </td>       <td>         <input type="text" value="5" class="prk_txt_style clsCal1_108" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredNoParfetch"><span class="spnrowset">5</span>  </td>    <td>   <input type="text" value="5" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedNoParfetch"><span class="spnrowset">5</span> </td> <td>  <input type="text" disabled="" value="15" class="prk_txt_style clsShow1_108" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPAfetch"><span class="spnrowset">15</span>  </td>   <td>  <input type="text" value="15" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedPAfetch"><span class="spnrowset spnadd">15</span>     </td>   </tr>    <tr class="id_109">  <td>2</td> <td>Two wheeler</td>  <td> <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPR2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>  </td>  <td>    <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedPR2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>    </td> <td>  <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style clsCal2_108" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredNoPar2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span> </td> <td> <input type="text" value="3" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedNoPar2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span> </td>  <td>    <input type="text" disabled="" value="9" class="prk_txt_style clsShow2_108" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPA2fetch"><span class="spnrowset">9</span> </td>  <td>   <input type="text" value="9.00" class="prk_txt_style" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="txtprovidedPA2fetch"><span class="spnrowset spnadd">9.00</span>  </td></tr> <tr class="id_109"> <td>3</td>  <td>bicycle</td><td>    <input type="text" value="3" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style" id="txtrequiredPR3fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>  </td> <td> <input type="text" value="3" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style" id="txtprovidedPR3fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>    </td><td> <input type="text" value="3" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style clsCal3_108" id="txtrequiredNP3fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span> </td> <td>  <input type="text" value="3" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style" id="txtprovidedNP3fetch"><span class="spnrowset">3</span>  </td>  <td> <input type="text" disabled="" value="0" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" id="txtrequiredPA3fetch" class="prk_txt_style clsShow3_108"><span class="spnrowset">0</span>  </td>  td>   <input type="text" value="0.00" style="width: 105px; margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="prk_txt_style" id="txtprovidedPA3fetch"><span class="spnrowset spnadd">0.00</span> </td></tr>';
```

**HTML markup:**

```
multiple Factor
<input type="text" value="3" tabindex="1" id="myMultipleFactor" />

<br><br>
<div id="apnd_tr" class="btnStyle">Append TR</div><br>
    <div id="mValue" class="btnStyle">Calculate Value</div>
<br>
<table border="1" id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th width="5%" rowspan="2">Sr. No.</th>
        <th width="20%" rowspan="2">Type of Parking</th>
        <th width="25%" colspan="2">Parking ratio</th>
        <th width="25%" colspan="2">No. of Parking</th>
        <th width="25%" colspan="2">Calculated Done</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="12.5%">Required</th>
        <th width="12.5%">Provided</th>
        <th width="12.5%">Required</th>
        <th width="12.5%">Provided</th>
        <th width="12.5%">Required</th>
        <th width="12.5%">Provided</th>
    </tr>
    <tr > <td class="Total_result" colspan="8">Total</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly it does not appear that you are setting the child elements of the elements with the class of the generated id.  Where are you holding the calculated value for each element? I don't see where that is happening.

Comment: I think its bcaz ur incomplete td tag in htmls @row_2cnt -".. td>   <input type="text" value=" .."  http://jsfiddle.net/SSNfZ/15/

Comment: @Neha: thanks for reply, but my span html is changed, why not only textbox not gets updated, no thats not the issue after adding td it wotn gives desire output

Comment: I am confuse, I donot see where u updating the textbox?

Comment: @Neha: do step like 1) click button Append tr , 2) enter numeric value to multiplefactor textbox , then check the table last column (caclutated provided section 1st row (fourwheel)) there span value get changed but not the textbox behind span

Comment: few thought to add on arrParkingRowIds.length comes 0 if u not update values in textbox after appending tr update txtbox and than press calculate value -> this will alert ur fetch fourwheel last column span tag.

Comment: @Neha: have you followed step i mention in my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some R&d I figured it out what is causing issue .. its the text input html which are display:none and some places disabled,  its not getting update or not stay editable (maybe jquery bug ).

Related thread on the issue -- - [stackoverflow.com/questions/3537326/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537326/jquery-val-inside-display-none)

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SSNfZ/22/)

There can be two way to fix it ..

- Quick and easy fix is to use `element.attr("value" , "yourvalue")`  instead of using`element.val()`.
- Alternative fix to change type text to hidden (all places its just one e.g.)

.

```
 <input type="text" value="2323232323" tabindex="1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 80% ! important; display: none;" id="TextTitleFetch" class="prk_txt_style" />

<input type="hidden" value="2323232323" tabindex="1"  id="TextTitleFetch" class="prk_txt_style" />
```

As much I understand those inputs are mostly for form data or internal use so u can keep them hidden type.

Updated input [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SSNfZ/19/)

Comment: I also found this .. maybe this is the issue -- rather than set .val() u can do .attr("vlaue" , "") - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537326/jquery-val-inside-display-none

Comment: *+1* Thank you very much.  the link you provided in your comment helpd me, thanks again for giving your precious time :)

Comment: Update your answer, put ur above comment in answer, so i will accept this as answer

Comment: thanks option one works for me , also 2nd option is not suits in my scenareo, as i need both txtbox and div, div will dilpay in normal mode and on edit mode i.e row get editable mode so div will hide and textbox behind div will display.