# jQuery strange "undefined" reaction while getting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, undefined

I have a problem with the variable. So i'm making post form with jQuery. The input that i'm trying to get the info from i s hidden:

```
<input id="company_id" name="company_id" type="hidden" value="4">
```

And the jQuery code is like this:

```
if (button == 'rem') {
    var term = $("#userlist").val();
    var comid = $( "#company_id").val();
    $.post('/delfromgroup', { id: term, cid: comid }, function(html){ 
        console.log(comid);
        $("#list").fadeOut("slow",function() { 
            $("#list").html($(html).filter("#error")); 
            $("#list").fadeIn("slow"); 
        });
    });
}
```

The first time, when i hit the button, its fine... the console.log says the right number, but after the first time, everytime when i press the button, the value is "undefined". Why can't read the html code correctly after the first time? Any suggestions? Thank you :)

Comment: add the click code+button and  `userlist` html too

Comment: By far the best way to figure this out is to *debug* it. Use the powerful debugger built into your browser (search for "xxx dev tools" where "xxx" is your browser), set a breakpoint on the first line of the ajax callback, another on the first line of the fadeOut callback, and step through the code, looking at your variables, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your hidden field `company_id` would be inside `#list` then it will be removed by the jQuery code (`fadeOut()`) you have used.

So when you call it next time, you are getting undefined.

Comment: There's nothing in the OP's question suggesting that the input is in #list. *(not my dv)*

Comment: this might actually be the problem here. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153516/5393271) @Nicox

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I am assuming as a possibility.

Comment: I haven't used jQuery (just vanilla and TS), but as far as I could make out from the docs, fadeOut just modifies the opacity and finally the display. That does *not* remove the code. Although, as @sTx pointed out, there are problems with using .val() with display as none. The description provided is most probably wrong.

Comment: I don't think it would be the fadeOut, but more that he is replacing the html.  But I'd say this answer is pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Oh my god... it's not inside the #list, but it's inside the other div, which is refreshing too. I don't even realize that. Thank you :)